# Twitter time stamps an hour off. Returns to normal after browser refresh

Tags: twitter, time-zone

Something strange is going on. The newest posts in my feed always appear to be an hour ahead, but when I hit refresh in Chrome the times return to normal. Has anyone experienced this before? Could this be the result of an overlooked setting somewhere, a bug, or, at worse, a virus that the scans overlooked?

Answer (score 1):

My system clock was just synced wrong...

Move along. Nothing to see here.